# Mathematica Integrate gives back the integrand

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, integral, indefinite, hyperbolic-function

i'm trying to Integrate the following function:

```
(q (1 + q) - E^-q Sinh[q])/(-q + Cosh[q] Sinh[q]) - (
 2 q Tanh[q])/(-q + Cosh[q] Sinh[q])
```

I already solved it numerically but i really need the indefinite integral so used:

```
 In[67]:= Integrate[(
  q (1 + q) - E^-q Sinh[q])/(-q + Cosh[q] Sinh[q]) - (
  2 q Tanh[q])/(-q + Cosh[q] Sinh[q]), q]
```

but as output i get back the integrand again:

```
 Out[67]= \[Integral]((
     q (1 + q) - E^-q Sinh[q])/(-q + Cosh[q] Sinh[q]) - (
     2 q Tanh[q])/(-q + Cosh[q] Sinh[q])) \[DifferentialD]q
```

any suggestions on how to perform this computation correctly?
thanks in advance

Comment: math.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths

Comment: shall I repost the question there?

Comment: You should post the question on [mathematica.stackexchange.com](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

You can decompose this integral:

```
eq = (q (1 + q) - E^-q Sinh[q])/(-q + 
  Cosh[q] Sinh[q]) - (2 q Tanh[q])/(-q + Cosh[q] Sinh[q]);
Integrate[#, q] & /@ Simplify /@ Expand[eq]
```

One part of this integral can be done, rest contains simplest, but still no expressed in standard mathematical functions integrals.

[image]

You can do these integrals numerically, or search approximated form, for example using series expansion.

Exemplary series expansion you can find on link:
[wolframalpha.com](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5C[Integral]q%5E2%2F%28-2%20q%20%2B%20Sinh[2%20q]%29)